# XSLT replace attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following xml

```
 <ExternalAssessmentRequest>
    <ApplicationData Lender="Test">
        <LiabilityList>
            <RequestedLoan Identifier="New1" BaseAmount="250000" LoanAccountFees="100" LoanAccountLMI="2000" LoanTerm="25" LoanTermMonths="6" Product="Basic Variable" Repurposing="No" PrimaryPurpose="OwnerOccupied" TaxDeductible="No" InterestRate="0.075" ProductID="Product1" PaymentType="InterestOnly" ABSCode="123">
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Feature Code="SupaPackage"/>
            </RequestedLoan>
        </LiabilityList>
    </ApplicationData>
    <AdditionalAssessment Lender="MegaBank">
        <RequestedLoan Product="Supa Variable" ProductID="Product2"/>
    </AdditionalAssessment>
</ExternalAssessmentRequest>
```

I need to use Xpath to create two seperate  elements. One is the existing  and the other one is again the existing  BUT only the elements and attributes specified in  must be replaced.

So the end result should be

```
<ExternalAssessmentRequest>
    <ApplicationData Lender="Test">
        <LiabilityList>
            <RequestedLoan Identifier="New1" BaseAmount="250000" LoanAccountFees="100" LoanAccountLMI="2000" LoanTerm="25" LoanTermMonths="6" Product="Basic Variable" Repurposing="No" PrimaryPurpose="OwnerOccupied" TaxDeductible="No" InterestRate="0.075" ProductID="Product1" PaymentType="InterestOnly" ABSCode="123">
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Feature Code="SupaPackage"/>
            </RequestedLoan>
        </LiabilityList>
    </ApplicationData>
    <ApplicationData Lender="MegaBank">
        <LiabilityList>
            <RequestedLoan Identifier="New1" BaseAmount="250000" LoanAccountFees="100" LoanAccountLMI="2000" LoanTerm="25" LoanTermMonths="6" Product="Supa Variable" Repurposing="No" PrimaryPurpose="OwnerOccupied" TaxDeductible="No" InterestRate="0.075" ProductID="Product2" PaymentType="InterestOnly" ABSCode="123">
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Feature Code="SupaPackage"/>
            </RequestedLoan>
        </LiabilityList>
    </ApplicationData>
</ExternalAssessmentRequest>
```

Pleaseeee help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer addresses the initially unstated requirement that there be a number of arbitrarily-named child elements of `<LiabilityList>`:

```
t:\ftemp>type attrs.xml 
 <ExternalAssessmentRequest>
    <ApplicationData Lender="Test">
        <LiabilityList>
            <RequestedLoan Identifier="New1" BaseAmount="250000" LoanAccountFees="100" LoanAccountLMI="2000" LoanTerm="25" LoanTermMonths="6" Product="Basic Variable" Repurposing="No" PrimaryPurpose="OwnerOccupied" TaxDeductible="No" InterestRate="0.075" ProductID="Product1" PaymentType="InterestOnly" ABSCode="123">
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Feature Code="SupaPackage"/>
            </RequestedLoan>
        </LiabilityList>
    </ApplicationData>
    <AdditionalAssessment Lender="MegaBank">
        <RequestedLoan Product="Supa Variable" ProductID="Product2"/>
    </AdditionalAssessment>
</ExternalAssessmentRequest>
t:\ftemp>call xslt attrs.xml attrs.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ExternalAssessmentRequest>
    <ApplicationData Lender="Test">
        <LiabilityList>
            <RequestedLoan Identifier="New1" BaseAmount="250000" LoanAccountFees="100" LoanAccountLMI="2000" LoanTerm="25" LoanTermMonths="6" Product="Basic Variable" Repurposing="No" PrimaryPurpose="OwnerOccupied" TaxDeductible="No" InterestRate="0.075" ProductID="Product1" PaymentType="InterestOnly" ABSCode="123">
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Feature Code="SupaPackage"/>
            </RequestedLoan>
        </LiabilityList>
    </ApplicationData>
    <ApplicationData Lender="MegaBank"><LiabilityList><RequestedLoan Identifier="New1" BaseAmount="250000" LoanAccountFees="100" LoanAccountLMI="2000" LoanTerm="25" LoanTermMonths="6" Product="Supa Variable" Repurposing="No" PrimaryPurpose="OwnerOccupied" TaxDeductible="No" InterestRate="0.075" ProductID="Product2" PaymentType="InterestOnly" ABSCode="123">
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Feature Code="SupaPackage"/>
            </RequestedLoan></LiabilityList></ApplicationData>
</ExternalAssessmentRequest>
t:\ftemp>type attrs.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="AdditionalAssessment">
  <ApplicationData>
    <!--preserve data attributes-->
    <xsl:copy-of select="/*/ApplicationData/@*"/>
    <!--override with additional attributes-->
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <LiabilityList>
      <!--remember the location of the additional assessment information-->
      <xsl:variable name="additional" select="."/>
      <!--preserve each of the items in the liability list-->
      <xsl:for-each select="/*/ApplicationData/LiabilityList/*">
        <!--preserve data element-->
        <xsl:copy>
          <!--preserve data attributes-->
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <!--override with additional attributes-->
          <xsl:copy-of select="$additional/*[name(.)=name(current())]/@*"/>
          <!--preserve data descendants-->
          <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </LiabilityList>
  </ApplicationData>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!--identity for all other nodes-->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
t:\ftemp>rem Done!
```

Comment: This does not meet your requirement because, again, you did not fully specify what you need.  You are making even more extra work for volunteers.

Comment: There will be other elements other than LiabilityList inside ApplicationData, there is <AssetList></AssetList><IncomeList></IncomeList><ApplicantList></ApplicantList><‌​FeeList></FeeList> and some other elements which should be copied aswell

Comment: I've posted a more detailed question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776631/xslt-replace-elemetns-and-attributes

Answer (score 0):

The answer relies on knowing that you can redefine an element's attribute's value any number of times before beginning adding the element's content.  In my solution I copy the data attributes then simply copy over them with the additional attributes.

```
t:\ftemp>type attrs.xml 
 <ExternalAssessmentRequest>
    <ApplicationData Lender="Test">
        <LiabilityList>
            <RequestedLoan Identifier="New1" BaseAmount="250000" LoanAccountFees="100" LoanAccountLMI="2000" LoanTerm="25" LoanTermMonths="6" Product="Basic Variable" Repurposing="No" PrimaryPurpose="OwnerOccupied" TaxDeductible="No" InterestRate="0.075" ProductID="Product1" PaymentType="InterestOnly" ABSCode="123">
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Feature Code="SupaPackage"/>
            </RequestedLoan>
        </LiabilityList>
    </ApplicationData>
    <AdditionalAssessment Lender="MegaBank">
        <RequestedLoan Product="Supa Variable" ProductID="Product2"/>
    </AdditionalAssessment>
</ExternalAssessmentRequest>
t:\ftemp>call xslt attrs.xml attrs.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ExternalAssessmentRequest>
    <ApplicationData Lender="Test">
        <LiabilityList>
            <RequestedLoan Identifier="New1" BaseAmount="250000" LoanAccountFees="100" LoanAccountLMI="2000" LoanTerm="25" LoanTermMonths="6" Product="Basic Variable" Repurposing="No" PrimaryPurpose="OwnerOccupied" TaxDeductible="No" InterestRate="0.075" ProductID="Product1" PaymentType="InterestOnly" ABSCode="123">
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Feature Code="SupaPackage"/>
            </RequestedLoan>
        </LiabilityList>
    </ApplicationData>
    <ApplicationData Lender="MegaBank"><LiabilityList><RequestedLoan Identifier="New1" BaseAmount="250000" LoanAccountFees="100" LoanAccountLMI="2000" LoanTerm="25" LoanTermMonths="6" Product="Supa Variable" Repurposing="No" PrimaryPurpose="OwnerOccupied" TaxDeductible="No" InterestRate="0.075" ProductID="Product2" PaymentType="InterestOnly" ABSCode="123">
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Feature Code="SupaPackage"/>
            </RequestedLoan></LiabilityList></ApplicationData>
</ExternalAssessmentRequest>
t:\ftemp>type attrs.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="AdditionalAssessment">
  <ApplicationData>
    <!--preserve data attributes-->
    <xsl:copy-of select="/*/ApplicationData/@*"/>
    <!--override with additional attributes-->
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <LiabilityList>
      <RequestedLoan>
        <!--preserve data attributes-->
        <xsl:copy-of 
          select="/*/ApplicationData/LiabilityList/RequestedLoan/@*"/>
        <!--override with additional attributes-->
        <xsl:copy-of select="RequestedLoan/@*"/>
        <!--preserve data descendants-->
        <xsl:copy-of 
          select="/*/ApplicationData/LiabilityList/RequestedLoan/node()"/>
      </RequestedLoan>
    </LiabilityList>
  </ApplicationData>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!--identity for all other nodes-->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
t:\ftemp>rem Done!
```

Comment: Thanksss alot for the answer....just a small thing. You've only copied the RequestedLoan element in the second ApplicationData element. I need to copy everything from the Original ApplicationData but ONLY change the elements specified at <AdditionalAssessment>.

Comment: Sorry I know I didn't include this in my question :(

Comment: There are all these other elements <AssetList></AssetList><IncomeList></IncomeList><ApplicantList></ApplicantList><FeeList></FeeList> inside applciation data which should be copied aswel

Comment: You make extra work for volunteers when you don't state your requirement fully.  Please find an alternate solution that I just posted.

Comment: I really appreciate your answers, so sorry about the inconvenience.