# XSLT replace elemetns and attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following xml

```
 <ExternalAssessmentRequest>

</ExternalAssessmentRequest>
```

HElppppppppp please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This relies on being able to override attributes simply by copying over them:

```
t:\ftemp>type attrs.xml 
 <ExternalAssessmentRequest>
    <ApplicationData Lender="Test">
        <LiabilityList>
            <RequestedLoan Identifier="New1" BaseAmount="250000" LoanAccountFees="100" LoanAccountLMI="2000" LoanTerm="25" LoanTermMonths="6" Product="Basic Variable" Repurposing="No" PrimaryPurpose="OwnerOccupied" TaxDeductible="No" InterestRate="0.075" ProductID="Product1" PaymentType="InterestOnly" ABSCode="123">
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Feature Code="SupaPackage"/>
            </RequestedLoan>
        </LiabilityList>
        <AssetList>
            <Asset Identifier="Asset1" Security="Yes" Purpose="OwnerOccupied" Value="500000" Transaction="Owns" PurchasingPrice="0" PurchasingCosts="0" Priority="Second" PropertyType="String" Description="1 Test Street, Sydney" Basis="V" Type="DetachedHouse" PrimarySecurity="Yes" MaxLendingValLtdByGtee="0" ConstructionCosts="0" Postcode="2000" TitleType="Freehold" PropertyStatus="Established" OwnerBuilder="No" LandHectares="0">
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2" Percentage="0.5"/>
            </Asset>
            <Fund Identifier="Fund1" Amount="1000" Description="Slush Fund"/>
        </AssetList>
        <IncomeList>
            <Income Identifier="Income1" GrossAmount="80000" Taxable="Yes" Type="Personal" Description="Rental Income" RentalAsset="Asset1" IncomeType="Rental" NonRecurring="No" Year="2013">
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2" Percentage="0.5"/>
            </Income>
        </IncomeList>
        <ApplicantList>
            <Household Children="0" AdditionalAdults="0" Postcode="2000" Description="1 Test St, Sydney" Boarding="Yes">
                <Person Identifier="Applicant1" Name="John Smith" Partner="Applicant2" Partnered="Yes" CustomerDurationInMonths="0" PermanentResident="Yes" CountryOfResidence="Australia" DischargedBankrupts="0"/>
                <Person Identifier="Applicant2" Name="Jane Smith" Partner="Applicant1" Partnered="Yes" CustomerDurationInMonths="0" PermanentResident="Yes" CountryOfResidence="Australia" DischargedBankrupts="0"/>
            </Household>
            <Company Identifier="Company1" Name="Tardis">
                <Director RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
            </Company>
        </ApplicantList>
        <FeeList>
            <Fee Identifier="Fee1" Amount="100" PaidAmount="0" Description="Application Fee" DateOfPayment="1967-08-13" Capitalised="No"/>
        </FeeList>
    </ApplicationData>
    <AdditionalAssessment Lender="MegaBank">
        <RequestedLoan Product="Supa Variable" ProductID="Product2"/>
    </AdditionalAssessment>
</ExternalAssessmentRequest>
t:\ftemp>call xslt attrs.xml attrs.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ExternalAssessmentRequest>
    <ApplicationData Lender="Test">
        <LiabilityList>
            <RequestedLoan Identifier="New1" BaseAmount="250000" LoanAccountFees="100" LoanAccountLMI="2000" LoanTerm="25" LoanTermMonths="6" Product="Basic Variable" Repurposing="No" PrimaryPurpose="OwnerOccupied" TaxDeductible="No" InterestRate="0.075" ProductID="Product1" PaymentType="InterestOnly" ABSCode="123">
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Feature Code="SupaPackage"/>
            </RequestedLoan>
        </LiabilityList>
        <AssetList>
            <Asset Identifier="Asset1" Security="Yes" Purpose="OwnerOccupied" Value="500000" Transaction="Owns" PurchasingPrice="0" PurchasingCosts="0" Priority="Second" PropertyType="String" Description="1 Test Street, Sydney" Basis="V" Type="DetachedHouse" PrimarySecurity="Yes" MaxLendingValLtdByGtee="0" ConstructionCosts="0" Postcode="2000" TitleType="Freehold" PropertyStatus="Established" OwnerBuilder="No" LandHectares="0">
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2" Percentage="0.5"/>
            </Asset>
            <Fund Identifier="Fund1" Amount="1000" Description="Slush Fund"/>
        </AssetList>
        <IncomeList>
            <Income Identifier="Income1" GrossAmount="80000" Taxable="Yes" Type="Personal" Description="Rental Income" RentalAsset="Asset1" IncomeType="Rental" NonRecurring="No" Year="2013">
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2" Percentage="0.5"/>
            </Income>
        </IncomeList>
        <ApplicantList>
            <Household Children="0" AdditionalAdults="0" Postcode="2000" Description="1 Test St, Sydney" Boarding="Yes">
                <Person Identifier="Applicant1" Name="John Smith" Partner="Applicant2" Partnered="Yes" CustomerDurationInMonths="0" PermanentResident="Yes" CountryOfResidence="Australia" DischargedBankrupts="0"/>
                <Person Identifier="Applicant2" Name="Jane Smith" Partner="Applicant1" Partnered="Yes" CustomerDurationInMonths="0" PermanentResident="Yes" CountryOfResidence="Australia" DischargedBankrupts="0"/>
            </Household>
            <Company Identifier="Company1" Name="Tardis">
                <Director RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
            </Company>
        </ApplicantList>
        <FeeList>
            <Fee Identifier="Fee1" Amount="100" PaidAmount="0" Description="Application Fee" DateOfPayment="1967-08-13" Capitalised="No"/>
        </FeeList>
    </ApplicationData><ApplicationData Lender="MegaBank">
        <LiabilityList>
            <RequestedLoan Identifier="New1" BaseAmount="250000" LoanAccountFees="100" LoanAccountLMI="2000" LoanTerm="25" LoanTermMonths="6" Product="Supa Variable" Repurposing="No" PrimaryPurpose="OwnerOccupied" TaxDeductible="No" InterestRate="0.075" ProductID="Product2" PaymentType="InterestOnly" ABSCode="123">
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Feature Code="SupaPackage"/>
            </RequestedLoan>
        </LiabilityList>
        <AssetList>
            <Asset Identifier="Asset1" Security="Yes" Purpose="OwnerOccupied" Value="500000" Transaction="Owns" PurchasingPrice="0" PurchasingCosts="0" Priority="Second" PropertyType="String" Description="1 Test Street, Sydney" Basis="V" Type="DetachedHouse" PrimarySecurity="Yes" MaxLendingValLtdByGtee="0" ConstructionCosts="0" Postcode="2000" TitleType="Freehold" PropertyStatus="Established" OwnerBuilder="No" LandHectares="0">
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2" Percentage="0.5"/>
            </Asset>
            <Fund Identifier="Fund1" Amount="1000" Description="Slush Fund"/>
        </AssetList>
        <IncomeList>
            <Income Identifier="Income1" GrossAmount="80000" Taxable="Yes" Type="Personal" Description="Rental Income" RentalAsset="Asset1" IncomeType="Rental" NonRecurring="No" Year="2013">
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1" Percentage="0.5"/>
                <Applicant RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2" Percentage="0.5"/>
            </Income>
        </IncomeList>
        <ApplicantList>
            <Household Children="0" AdditionalAdults="0" Postcode="2000" Description="1 Test St, Sydney" Boarding="Yes">
                <Person Identifier="Applicant1" Name="John Smith" Partner="Applicant2" Partnered="Yes" CustomerDurationInMonths="0" PermanentResident="Yes" CountryOfResidence="Australia" DischargedBankrupts="0"/>
                <Person Identifier="Applicant2" Name="Jane Smith" Partner="Applicant1" Partnered="Yes" CustomerDurationInMonths="0" PermanentResident="Yes" CountryOfResidence="Australia" DischargedBankrupts="0"/>
            </Household>
            <Company Identifier="Company1" Name="Tardis">
                <Director RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
            </Company>
        </ApplicantList>
        <FeeList>
            <Fee Identifier="Fee1" Amount="100" PaidAmount="0" Description="Application Fee" DateOfPayment="1967-08-13" Capitalised="No"/>
        </FeeList>
    </ApplicationData>

</ExternalAssessmentRequest>
t:\ftemp>type attrs.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

<!--remember the location of the additional assessment information-->
<xsl:variable name="additional" select="/*/AdditionalAssessment"/>

<xsl:template match="ApplicationData">
  <!--preserve original data-->
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <!--now make duplicate-->
  <ApplicationData>
    <!--preserve data attributes-->
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <!--override with additional attributes-->
    <xsl:copy-of select="$additional/@*"/>
    <!--process children looking for modifications to attributes-->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="overrideAttributes"/>
  </ApplicationData>
</xsl:template>

<!--copy the element and override attributes form the additional assessment-->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="overrideAttributes">
  <xsl:copy>
    <!--preserve data attributes-->
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <!--override with additional attributes-->
    <xsl:copy-of select="$additional/*[name(.)=name(current())]/@*"/>
    <!--manipulate the descendants-->
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="overrideAttributes"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--remove the original additional assessment-->
<xsl:template match="AdditionalAssessment"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!--identity for all other nodes-->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
t:\ftemp>rem Done!
```

Comment: How can I replace ExternalAssessmentRequest with ApplicationDataBatch...Just want to change the main element's name

Comment: <ApplicationDataBatch><ApplicationData>.....</ApplicationData>.....and so on</ApplicationDataBatch>

Comment: Simply add to the stylesheet a template rule that matches on ExternalAssessmentRequest and creates ApplicationDataBatch.  I thought you were posting to StackOverflow with the challenging aspects of your problem, not the straightforward aspects of your problem.  Is there not some due diligence on your part that you can do before asking volunteers to do everything?